# Repeat string inside an array[] or List

Tags: c#, arrays, string, list, repeat

I have a string, for example "DNA" and length of the array/list = N. Is there anyway to insert the string into the array or List so that it becomes ["D", "N", "A", "D", "N", "A", "D", "N"]? I tried many things but nothing is giving me those last two letters.

I tried converting the string to char[], checking if the length of the list is < n and then  using .Take() to append the characters I need, but it doesn't work. And even if it did, it seems kinda clumsy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int N = 7;
string str = "DNA";
var result = string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(str, N).SelectMany(x => x).Take(N));
```

or

```
var result = string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(str, N/str.Length + 1).SelectMany(x => x)
             .Take(N));
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go :)

```
 class Program
 {
    public static readonly string dnaString ="DNA";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int counter = 7;
        List<string> stringList = new List<string>();
        for(int i=0;i< counter;i++)
        {
            stringList.Add(dnaString[i % dnaString.Length].ToString());
        }


     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`yield return`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) statement to generate an infinite sequence of your input, then slice it somewhere with `Take`:

```
int N = 10;
List<string> listStr = new List<string> { "D", "N", "A" };

List<string> result = Cycle(listStr).Take(N).ToList();


static IEnumerable<string> Cycle(IEnumerable<string> input)
{
    while(true)
    {
        foreach (var str in input)
           yield return str;
    }
}
```